# How to properly design statuses table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This question is more about what is the best approch to desgin a table that contains statuses of proccess in a system.

I have a proccess that can be in status: `init, waiting for price approve, sent, accepted,finished`

Status can be forward one step at a time or back 1 step at a time, meaning from `init` you can't jump to `sent` without passing throu `waitig for price approve`.

I designed the following table (`PostgreSQL` but it doesn't matter for the question):

```
CREATE TABLE status
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  backid Integer,
  forwardid integer,

  CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  CONSTRAINT backid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES status(id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  CONSTRAINT forward_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES status(id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Which basicly means:

```
id name                         backid  forwardid
1  init                                    2
2  waiting for price approve      1        3
3  sent                           2        4
4  accepted                       3        5
5  finished                       4
```

Note: There is no gurenntee that after `1` there will be `2`. In the future I can delete one of the lines and it might look like that:

```
id name                         backid  forwardid
1  init                                    3
3  sent                           1        4
4  accepted                       3        5
5  finished                       4
```

It's the same behavior as `Doubly linked list`.
The goal is that in the future if there will be a new status it will be insrted to the table and I won't have to do changes anywhere else. When the client ask to forward/back it will be done automaticly to the new "list" of statuses.

The thing is that this way seems a bit not ellegant. The insertion of new status will be the same algoritem as insertion to `Doubly linked list`. It seems like too much work and it doesn't seems proper work with `SQL` and DataBase abilities.

Can you suggest a better way to do that?

Comment: You don't really need the `forwardid` - especially if we are only talking about "tens of" status values (as opposed to e.g. thousands or millions)

Comment: But I can delete a status from the list. There is no gurenntee that after 3 there will be 4.

Comment: But the `backid` is enough to retrieve the hierarchy.

Comment: I see no point of keeping both `backid` and `forwardid`. only one of them is enough since they basically describe the same data.

Comment: You can keep a simple column for status order and with the proper stored procedures to insert / delete / update statuses simply get the next or last before status...

Comment: OK I can simpley write a query that will check who's `forwardid` is my id and with that info know who is my `backid`.  But still it seems a bit not very the database way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forwardid` is not needed and I think removing it makes life easier (although you *could* keep it if you think it will make your queries easier).

I would however not define the `id` column as `serial`. I would want to have control over the ids during insert and update.

Assuming your table definition you can query the whole hierarchy including some sort column using a [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive status_tree as (
   select id, name, backid, 1 as level
   from status
   where backid is null
   union all 
   select c.id, c.name, c.backid, p.level + 1
   from status c
     join status_tree p on p.id = c.backid
)
select *
from status_tree
order by level;
```

For your sample data this will return:

```
id | name                      | backid | level
---+---------------------------+--------+------
 1 | init                      |        |     1
 2 | waiting ror price approve |      1 |     2
 3 | sent                      |      2 |     3
 4 | accepted                  |      3 |     4
 5 | finished                  |      4 |     5
```

Inserting a new status is quite easy (and this is the point where a manually defined `id` makes life a bit easier:

```
-- create a new status that may be set after 'waiting ror price approve'
insert into status (id, name, backid) 
values (6, 'partially sent', 2);

-- now make the current 'sent' status an descendant of the new one
update status
  set backid = 6
where name = 'sent';
```

The above query now returns the following:

```
id | name                      | backid | level
---+---------------------------+--------+------
 1 | init                      |        |     1
 2 | waiting ror price approve |      1 |     2
 6 | partially sent            |      2 |     3
 3 | sent                      |      6 |     4
 4 | accepted                  |      3 |     5
 5 | finished                  |      4 |     6
```

The order of the status values does not reflect the "order" of the `id` column.

If you want you can create a view returning this information.

---

**Edit**

If you usually find the *next* status rather than looking at all of them, then you can flip the logic and store only the next one:

```
CREATE TABLE status
(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  next_status Integer references status
);

insert into status(id, name, next_status)
values 
(1,'init', 2),
(2,'waiting ror price approve', 3),
(3,'sent', 4),
(4,'accepted', 5),
(5,'finished', null);
```

To retrieve the next status this then only requires a single `select` statement (no recursion).

You can still get all status values in the correct order using a CTE, you just need to reverse the join condition:

```
with recursive status_tree as (
   select id, name, next_status, 1 as level
   from status
   where id = 1
   union all 
   select c.id, c.name, c.next_status, p.level + 1
   from status c
     join status_tree p on p.next_status = c.id
)
select *
from status_tree
order by level;
```

Inserting new nodes would be done the same way as with just the `backid` (just that you need to "re-link" the "other" row)

```
insert into status (id, name, next_status) 
values (6, 'partially sent', 3);

update status
  set next_status = 6
where name = 'waiting ror price approve';
```

Comment: Sound good. But I don't understand how the `waiting for price approve` will know that the next status is 6 `partially sent` and not 3 `sent`

Comment: @user2641077: if retrieving the next status is the usual thing to do,then you keeping only the id of the next status is probably more efficient. See my edit. Storing information that can  be derived from the current data is usually not a good idea that's why I'm suggesting ot only keep one of them - It also makes updating easier.

Comment: @user2641077: you said it yourself: "*There is no guarantee that after 3 there will be 4*", as soon as you delete and insert new rows, the numerical order is no longer correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7a56/1

Comment: Ok got it. I had a "dead lock" which cause the recursion to fail